# How to enable editing for the input field jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, input

In the provided form, the second input field has a default value, which is divided by 5 to update the third field. However, I need the flexibility to edit the value in the third field and have the final result (Total Visits per Year) updated accordingly, based on the inputs from the main form.

**[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twbr7p60/2/)**

```js
 //Average number of rooms 
    var avgrooms = (parseInt((jQuery("#numshops").val())) ) / 5;
    jQuery("#numrooms").val(avgrooms);

    
jQuery('#numofapples, #numshops, #numrooms, #avgcustomer').on('input',function() {
    
    var avgrooms = (parseInt((jQuery("#numshops").val())) ) / 5;
    jQuery("#numrooms").val(avgrooms);
            
    //Total annual visitors here
    var totalannualvisits = (parseInt((jQuery("#numofapples").val())) * parseInt(jQuery("#avgcustomer").val())) * avgrooms;
    jQuery("#totalvisitperyear").val(totalannualvisits);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-right">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="60%" valign="top">
          <label> 1. How many apples do you have? <br/>
                      <input name="" id="numofapples" placeholder="" type="number" required />
                    </label>
          <label> 2. How many shops do you have?<br/>
                      <input name="" id="numshops" type="number" value="10" placeholder="" required />
                    </label>
          <label> 3. Average Number of rooms per shop<br/>
                      <input name="" id="numrooms" type="number" value="" placeholder="" required />
                    </label>
          <label> 4. Average customer per store per day <br/>
                      <input name="" id="avgcustomer" type="number" placeholder="" required />
                    </label>

        </td>
        <td width="40%" valign="top">
          <p>Total visits per year </p>
          <input value="" type="text" name="" id="totalvisitperyear" />

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: For one move the function to a separate function so you can reuse it onload

Comment: The problem is that your recalculate *everything* on each input change.  Split the input event handlers (or better group them), move the rooms per shop calc to its own function (as above) so that it can be recalled.  Then only update number of rooms when shops changes.  As-is, the total calc doesn't use number of rooms.  https://jsfiddle.net/faok19Ly/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry, my bad. Total calculation should use the number of rooms. Have updated the code and fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check updated code below. For code re-usability, I have created functions and also added one condition for focused input to allow user to edit on third input.

```js
function updateAvgRooms() {
    var numroomsInput = jQuery("#numrooms");
    // Check if the numrooms input is focused
    var isNumRoomsFocused = numroomsInput.is(":focus");
    
    var avgrooms = parseInt(jQuery("#numshops").val()) / 5;
    if (!isNumRoomsFocused) {
        numroomsInput.val(avgrooms);
    }
}

  function updateTotalVisits() {
    var avgrooms = parseInt(jQuery("#numrooms").val());
    var totalannualvisits = parseInt(jQuery("#numofapples").val()) * parseInt(jQuery("#avgcustomer").val()) * avgrooms;
    jQuery("#totalvisitperyear").val(totalannualvisits);
  }

  // Initialize values
  updateAvgRooms();
  updateTotalVisits();

  jQuery('#numofapples, #numshops, #numrooms, #avgcustomer').on('input', function() {
    updateAvgRooms();
    updateTotalVisits();
  });

  jQuery('#numshops').on('input', function() {
    updateAvgRooms();
    updateTotalVisits();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-right">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td width="60%" valign="top">
          <label> 1. How many apples do you have? <br/>
            <input name="" id="numofapples" placeholder="" type="number" required />
          </label>
          <label> 2. How many shops do you have?<br/>
            <input name="" id="numshops" type="number" value="10" placeholder="" required />
          </label>
          <label> 3. Average Number of rooms per shop<br/>
            <input name="" id="numrooms" type="number" value="" placeholder="" required />
          </label>
          <label> 4. Average customer per store per day <br/>
            <input name="" id="avgcustomer" type="number" placeholder="" required />
          </label>

        </td>
        <td width="40%" valign="top">
          <p>Total visits per year </p>
          <input value="" type="text" name="" id="totalvisitperyear" />

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</form>
```